# Faster alternative to JsonPath in Java

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

JsonPath seems to be pretty slow for large JSON files.

In my project, I'd like a user to be able to pass an entire query as a string.  I used JsonPath because it lets you do an entire query like `$.store.book[3].price` all at once by doing `JsonPath.read(fileOrString, "$.store.book[3].price", new Filter[0])`.  Is there a faster method to interact with JSON files in Javascript?  It would be ideal to be able to pass the entire query as a string, but I'll write a parser if I have to.  Any ideas?

Even small optimizations would be helpful.  For instance, I'm currently reading from a JSON file every time I query.  Would it be better just to copy the entire file into a string at the beginning and query to the string instead?

EDIT: To those of you saying "this is Javascript, not Java", well, it actually is Java.  JsonPath is a Javascript-like query language, but the file I am writing is most assuredly Java.  Only the query is written in Javascript.  Here's some info about JsonPath, and a snippet of code: https://code.google.com/p/json-path/

```
List toRet;
String query = "$.store.book[3].price";
try { 
    // if output is a list, good
    toRet = (List) JsonPath.read(filestring_, query, new Filter[0]);
} catch (ClassCastException cce) {
    // if output isn't a list, put it in a list
    Object outObj = null;
    try {
        outObj = JsonPath.read(filestring_, query, new Filter[0]);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new DataSourceException("Invalid file!\n", e, DataSourceException.UNKNOWN);
    }
```

Comment: If you just use `"$.store.book[3].price"` as query, then it would probably be faster to directly access the property once you parsed the JSON. The only thing I could find about JSONPath is this (https://code.google.com/p/jsonpath/source/browse/trunk/src/js/jsonpath.js) is unmaintained since 2008 (just saying).

Comment: Here's info about it, it looks like it was updated in 2012.  (Admittedly it's not exactly the greatest thing in the world, but it was easier than writing my own JSON query parser from scratch.  https://code.google.com/p/json-path/

Comment: Oh. It was not clear from the code (and the tags) that it's about Java. And I didn't notice that the tags were changed by another user. Sorry!